# Why would some sites say their web site may not work properly in private browsing

Tags: google-chrome, browser, safari, firefox-addon, private

I have recently seen this in a website

> Our webpage will not work correctly in Private Mode

Does anybody know why exactly some sites might not function in private browsing?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion because of the cookies stored in the browser. Some sites store preferences in the cookies to ease the user experience, and when you leave the private mode all the cookies and stored data is deleted

Also i have to guess that they try to scare the user because its a common practice to add traking data to explore marketing trends

https://www.theverge.com/2017/9/14/16308138/apple-safari-11-advertiser-groups-cookie-tracking-letter

Comment: but cookies are deleted the browsing session ?

Comment: Cookies and all data downloaded (like data in the field forms) are deleted when you finish using the private mode (closing the private window or ending the browser session) im not shure how they detect private mode because according to some articles it works the same as a normal browsing session https://www.howtogeek.com/117776/htg-explains-how-private-browsing-works-and-why-it-doesnt-offer-complete-privacy/